# Celery .delay() works synchronously, not delaying

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, rabbitmq, celery

I have a Django project with Celery background and periodic tasks. I started worker process a year ago, and periodic tasks work well. However, I just found that calling asynchronous functions main server code doesn't work, `apply_async()`/`delay()` lead to synchronous executing of a function just like without using them. How can I solve the problem? My Celery version is 4.2. Here is my Celery settings file:

```
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

broker_url = 'amqp://<user>:<password>@localhost:5672/{project}'
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'MyProject.settings')

app = Celery('<project>', broker=broker_url)

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.conf.update (
    CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER='json',
    CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=['json'],
    CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER='json',
    CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER=False,
    BROKER_URL=broker_url,
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database.DatabaseBackend',
    CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER=True,
)
```

And this is my test code:

```
from general.celery import app
from time import sleep

@app.task
def fun():
    for i in range(5):
        print('Sleeping')
        sleep(2)
    print('Awake')

def test():
    print('Begin')
    fun.apply_async(countdown=10)
    print('End')
```

It leads to the immediate output:

```
Begin
Sleeping
...
```

---

I also checked Celery's `inspect`:

```
from celery.task.control import inspect
print(inspect().stats())
```

It described the following states:

```
{
    'broker': {
        'failover_strategy': 'round-robin',
        'ssl': False,
        'transport': 'amqp',
        'heartbeat': 120.0,
        'transport_options': {},
        'insist': False,
        'alternates': [],
        'connect_timeout': 4,
        'userid': '<user>',
        'hostname': '127.0.0.1',
        'login_method': 'AMQPLAIN',
        'port': 5672,
        'uri_prefix': None,
        'virtual_host': '<project>'
    },
    'total': {},
    'prefetch_count': 8,
    'clock': '2299',
    'pool': {
        'put-guarded-by-semaphore': False,
        'max-concurrency': 2,
        'max-tasks-per-child': 'N/A',
        'writes': {
            'avg': '0.00%',
            'inqueues': {
                'total': 2,
                'active': 0
            },
            'total': 0,
            'raw': '',
            'all': '',
            'strategy': None
        },
        'timeouts': [0, 0],
        'processes': [28728, 28729]
    },
    'pid': 28722,
    'rusage': {
        'stime': 0.3959,
        'idrss': 0,
        'maxrss': 57220,
        'inblock': 2552,
        'minflt': 24279,
        'majflt': 3,
        'msgsnd': 0,
        'ixrss': 0,
        'nswap': 0,
        'nivcsw': 31,
        'isrss': 0,
        'nvcsw': 3326,
        'utime': 2.492,
        'msgrcv': 0,
        'nsignals': 0,
        'oublock': 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you explicitly set `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER=True` ([docs for 3.1](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/configuration.html#celery-always-eager)) in your `app.conf.update()` call, so Celery is executing in synchonous mode.

It is deprecated and renamed to `task_always_eager` ([docs for latest 4.2](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-task_always_eager))  but still might be recognized by your Celery v4.2